# Блокировка сайтов в хроме по времени без использования прокси

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Цель - в хроме максимально гибко заблокировать доступ к интернету кроме пары сайтов - локальными средствами. ТАм есть функция - блокировки отдельный сайтов в черный список, но она не поддерживает синтаксис `http://*` - а вот обратной функции не нашёл.
Пока есть идея реализовать средствами iptables, но по определенным причинам - делать этого бы не хотелось. Нужна гибкость - менять по крону iptables не лучший вариант. 
Так же родными средствами хрома подобная задача вроде бы не решается.

Answer (score 1):

насколько мне известно, подобных встроенных средств нет ни в одном популярном браузере.

вы можете воспользоваться, например, каким-нибудь локальным прокси-сервером (тем же *squid-ом*), запретив/разрешив в нём всё, что необходимо, и настроив браузер на работу через этот прокси-сервер.

Comment: Александр, прокси - это дефолтный вариант) Как раз интересует именно альтернативные решения)