# Как заблокировать все переводчики или большинство в локальной сети?

Tags: роутер, перевод, блокировки, локальная-сеть

И так, я понял что надо бы выучить английский язык(спустя 9 лет его изучения наконец дошло, что понадобится). Но проблема заключается в том как можно заблокировать все сайты определённого типа у себя в локалке?

То есть, надо блокнуть все сайты-переводчики, чтобы не было соблазна переводить через них ВСЁ.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Может есть какой-то выход?

PS Возможно, это оффтопик, но я просто молю вас о помощи

Comment: Как вариант: "вы можете воспользоваться, например, каким-нибудь локальным прокси-сервером (тем же squid-ом), запретив/разрешив в нём всё, что необходимо, и настроив браузер на работу через этот прокси-сервер." [(источник)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478004/271103)

Comment: @mrEvgenX, это, конечно, хорошо, но надо чтобы во всей локалке заблокало